# Why is the output remaining the same?

Tags: java, output

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestCaseAbcd {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
        float x0;
        float a, c, mod;
        int num, ch = 0;
        double[] rNumbers;
        double[] rTemp;

        System.out.println("Enter the SEED value: ");
        System.out.println("x0 ");
        x0 = Float.parseFloat(stdin.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter the multiplier's value:");
        System.out.println("a: ");
        a = Float.parseFloat(stdin.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter the value of increment c and modulus m: ");
        System.out.println("c: ");
        c = Float.parseFloat(stdin.readLine());

        System.out.println("m: ");
        mod = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

        System.out.println("How many random nunbers u need? ");
        num = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

        rNUmbers = new double[num];              
        rTemp = new double[rNumbers.length];
        rTemp[0] = x0;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) 
        {
            if(i + 1 != num)
            {
                rTemp[i + 1] = (((rTemp[i] * a) + c) % mod);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rNumbers.length; i++) 
        {
            if (i + 1 != num) 
            {
                rNumbers[i] = rTemp[i] / mod;
            } 
            else 
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The PSEUDO random numbers are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rNumbers.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(rNumbers[i]);
        }

        double firstNum = rNumbers[0];

        System.out.println("1. Select Mutant 1 ");
        System.out.println("2. Select Mutant 2 ");
        System.out.println("3. Exit ");
    }
}
```

In the above code, the expected output should start from: `0.68`.
But, instead it started from:
`0.37`.
In fact, even after I changed the following code:

```
 rTemp[i+1] = ( ( (rTemp[i]*a) + c ) % mod);
```

to:

```
 rTemp[i+1] = ( ( (rTemp[i]/a) + c ) % mod);
```

The output still started from 0.37.
The input values are:

```
x0 = 37
a = 7
c = 9
m = 100
```

Please help me in analyzing the code so as that the output shouldn't start with `0.37`.

Summary of the problem: the code is producing the same number i.e. `0.37` no matter what the equation stated above in the code is modified to.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: In addition to the formatting issue, your code doesn't compile: where is isr declared, what are the arguments of BufferedReader constructor (in stdin declaration)...? Could you please fix it?

Comment: Are you running this from the command line?  Did you re-run `javac`?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new to this. I can upload a .txt file containing this code. Should I upload it??

Comment: What are the values in your array `x`?

Comment: Dude, I am so sorry...that's x0 and not x[0]

Comment: Guys, I have edited it!!.Hope you'll get it??

Comment: @arshajii..I've done what you said!!!

Comment: @C.Champagne I'v used the following: `BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(isr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the first value in `rTemp` to `37`, then you start printing from the first value. It only makes sense that the first value printed would be `0.37`.

```
x0 = 37
mod = 100
...
rTemp[0] = x0;
...
rNumbers[i] = rTemp[i] / mod;
...
System.out.println(rNumbers[i]);
```

To achieve the output you're looking for, change this:

```
rTemp[0] = x0;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) 
{
    if(i + 1 != num)
    {
        rTemp[i + 1] = (((rTemp[i] * a) + c) % mod);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
rTemp[0] = (((x0 * a) + c) % mod);

for (int i = 0; i < num-1; i++) 
{
    rTemp[i + 1] = (((rTemp[i] * a) + c) % mod);
}
```

On a side note, if all you really want is an array of psudo-random doubles, it's easier to do something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random(seed);
double[] rNumbers = new double[num];
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    rNumbers[i] = (double)rnd.nextInt(100) / 100;
```

For any given seed, you'll get the same array of doubles every time.

Comment: @Syon... **thanks a lot!!!!**  It worked!!!..mahn!! i m noob!!!lol anyways...thanks a lot...can we meet on facebook?? I mean, I might need more tips from you.. :)